# how to set any column's value same as auto increment id's value in single query in mysql,php

Tags: php, mysql, triggers, phpmyadmin

how to set any column's value same as auto increment id's value in mysql,php in single query,
if answer is trigger so please suggest how to do that?

my table:

```
id int : auto increment
my_id int : want same value as id
title varchar
```

Comment: Just curious? Why would you need that?

Comment: Set both columns to auto increment :P

Comment: actually i need for order column,by default it will be last,but we can change it in future

Comment: look i have one table,whenever I will add any record I want to set its order field to last,am fetching record with order by 'order' field,now if i will use id for order by then there are no chance to change the order in future

Comment: @HeinA.Grønnestad only the primary key can be an auto_increment

Comment: Why duplicate the data when you can just select the data again if you need to `SELECT id, id AS my_id FROM table`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by utilizing a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER tinsert_id BEFORE INSERT ON your_table FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 SET NEW.my_id= (SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_db' AND TABLE_NAME='your_table');
END
```

Above code isn´t tested, but it should work this way.

**Important:** Be also aware that above trigger is only valid for single row inserts. Also it is not safe for high concurrency applications. So I would highly recommend that you assign your my_id field a default value and based on your application update this field later with something more suitable.

Answer (score 0):

Should work:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER `update_my_id` BEFORE INSERT ON `tablename` FOR EACH ROW SET NEW.my_id = LAST_INSERT_ID() + 1;
```